# Is there a way to control a pivot table filter from a drop down list

Tags: excel

I'm trying to figure out if its possible to control a pivot table filter from a dropdown list. At the moment I'm trying to connect a data validation dropdown list. In my data sheet I have a column called "Effective States" (1st attachment). This creates a pivot table dropdown list that's pretty much unreadable (2nd Attachment). I know I can manually type state codes and get the desired result. I'd prefer to make something more user friendly. A dropdown list with each unique state code (3rd Attachment).  Is this possible? If so, suggestions are most welcome :)

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I think this is difficult to understand and answer. Minimally reproducible mock data would be helpful here (data, pivot set-up, and desired result).

Answer (score 0):

After a bit more research, I found the answer is both Yes and No. Yes it can be done, but not with the structure of the dataset I have.  The problem is where a cell has a set of comma delimited data as part of the data source. So if your data set doesn't include comma delimited data within a single cell, the way to make it work is through using Power Pivot and setting up a relationship between the data tables. Here's a snapshot and a link to a YouTube video showing how to do it.

[![Power Pivot diagram view][1]][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dp2Es.png

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2BY-M-NNyQI